# What is the cost of std::iter::once?

Tags: rust

If I have code like [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=06ec2b36ea946abbf46965f8316b2ef5):

```
pub fn f(x: u16) -> impl Iterator<Item = u16> {
    std::iter::once(0).chain((x >> 10)..x)
}
```

where I chain a constant in front of an iterator using `once`, do I pay an O(n) cost for it *when the iterator is consumed*? I can't tell from the assembly (other than that it definitely sets up an additional data structure in memory). How can I tell?

Comment: This is pure speculation (so I'll write a comment rather than an answer), but it's rather similar in concept to a `do`/`while` loop in other languages. It could be compiled to `let mut value = 0; loop { ...; value = match some_iterator.next() { Some(value) => value, None => break, }}`, which is barely any different to the equivalent `loop` using just `some_iterator`.

Comment: @kaya3 , yes except since I'm returning an iterator, the values are pulled and I can't tell if Rust still turns it into a do-while loop equivalent. The assembly only sets up the data structures. It doesn't execute.

Comment: Iterators must be consumed to execute.

Comment: @PitaJ Yes, question assumes iterator is consumed. I'll make it explicit.

Comment: `std::iter::once` returns a struct that is essentially just an `Option` wrapper where the [`Iterator::next` impl is just `Option::take`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/src/core/option.rs.html#2052-2054). The real interesting stuff happens in the [`Chain` type](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/src/core/iter/adapters/chain.rs.html#22-51).

Comment: Here is a Godbolt showing essentially the same optimized assembly for your examples: https://godbolt.org/z/EYsh86Wqh

Comment: And here's a version that's very similar, but with a large enough number to prevent unrolling the loop: https://godbolt.org/z/drjsf36va

Comment: @PitaJ That's using internal iteration, external iteration is costlier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already discussed, the cost of `once()` is O(1). The O(n) cost you are thinking about is from `chain()`, not `once()`, because, at least before optimizations, `<Chain as Iterator>::next()` has to at each step decide whether to take an item from the first iterator or the second one.

However, it is possible to avoid incurring that cost, by using *internal iteration* — iteration whose control flow is the responsibility of the iterator itself, so that `next()` does not need to be repeatedly called. The most `for`-like way is `for_each()`. If you look at the assembly produced by this code, you can see that it is much simpler in the version using `for_each()` in `main2()`:

```rust
pub fn f(x: u16) -> impl Iterator<Item = u16> {
    std::iter::once(0).chain((x >> 10)..x)
}

pub fn main1() -> u16 {
    let mut sum = 0;
    for item in f(3) {
        sum += std::hint::black_box(item);
    }
    sum
}

pub fn main2() -> u16 {    
    let mut sum = 0;
    f(3).for_each(|item| {
        sum += std::hint::black_box(item);
    });
    sum
}
```

(I used `std::hint::black_box()` to discourage optimizing the loops away to constants.)

The reason this helps is that `for_each()` is implemented in terms of `fold()`, and the `Chain` iterator [overrides the default implementation of `fold()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/iter/adapters/chain.rs.html#84-86) so that it calls the first iterator's own `fold()` and then the second iterator's. No conditionals for every item.

You don't have to explicitly use `for_each()` or `fold()` — you should expect that any iterator operation which *can* benefit from this, like `sum()` or `collect()`, will do so. In general, if you are looking for optimal iterator performance and things like `chain()` are involved, **try to express your operation using a single call to the iterator,** rather than `next()` or things that translate into `next()` such as a `for item in iter {}` loop.

But if you want to use control flow constructs like `continue` or `await`, you need a `for` loop.

Comment: Kevin, this explains it well, thanks. I don't expect to be able to use internal iteration, so I will incur the chain O(n) cost with a preceeding `once`. But, it sounds like if I translate the algorithm so that I can _suffix_ with a `once` instead of a prefix, then that will minimize the cost, because it will not have to repeatedly call an exhausted iterator.

Comment: @Ana The `Chain` iterator checks its own memory of whether the iterators are exhausted, rather than calling the wrapped iterator; you can [see the implementation here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/iter/adapters/chain.rs.html#22). But that check (if not optimized away) will have to happen on every call to next(), so it doesn't matter (at least ,not for this reason) which order the two iterators are in. But, at this level of micro-optimization, **everything we're saying is baseless speculation**; you have to benchmark the performance of the actual code. Likely there will be no difference.

Answer (score 1):

> where I chain a constant in front of an iterator using once, do I pay an O(n) cost for it?

O(n) of what n?

> in my head once translates into an if at runtime, which would suggest that it does.

Well code-wise `Once` is literally just a wrapper for an `Option`'s iterator, and what *that* does is call `take` on itself.

[`take` is](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/option.rs.html#1580):

```
mem::replace(self, None)
```

so there's no actual `if at runtime` in the `once`, the conditional is in the iteration protocol.

There are conditions in the `chain` because *it* needs to switch from the first to the second operator, so it gets a bit more complicated there.

> How can I tell?

Probably easier if you use godbolt, as it has a much better assembly view than the playground.

Comment: Then it sounds like there is an O(n) cost (n being the number of elements delivered by the chaining iterator). Just not an `if`.